# Using partial() on DRF's @action gives TypeError: "multiple values for argument"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, partial-application

I need similar `@action` detail routes on multiple ViewSets. I want to make sure they remain consistent. I don't want to put `@action(methods=["post"], detail=True, url_path="something")` in 20 places when I already know these parameters and the method handling the request will be the same everywhere.

My first attempt to solve htis was to put the method and its decorator in a base class and have my ViewSets inherit from it, but because decoration of methods is not inherited, DRF does not recognise my `@action`s as such in the inheriting classes. The methods get inherited but not the decorator.

So, to solve that, I could put `@action` everywhere but that would mean a duplication of its arguments in many places. I don't want that.

To avoid duplication, I am trying to specialise `@action` by using partial application. This will give me a custom `@action` decorator with the arguments which will be the same everywhere fixed in place.

This leaves me with something like this (example code):

```
specialised_action = partial(action, methods=["post"], detail=True, url_path="my-action-url")

class SomeViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    @specialised_action
    def action_handler(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("do something")
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error:

`TypeError: action() got multiple values for argument 'methods'`

My questions:

1. Why is `methods` passed multiple times?
2. How can I fix this?
3. Is there a better way to achieve consistent, duplication-free, `@action`s across many ViewSets?

Comment: *"partial application"*? What is that?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu See here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial partially applying a function means supplying some of its arguments. The result is another function taking the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `@action` isn't a decorator, it *returns* a decorator. So there is no need to use `partial()`.

Instead of:

```
specialised_action = partial(action, methods=["post"], detail=True, url_path="my-action-url")
```

Simply do:

```
specialised_action = action(methods=["post"], detail=True, url_path="my-action-url")
```

And I got my specialised version of `@action` with fixed arguments.

Comment: Good answer! Note though that some decorators are note reusable - it may be necessary to use a partial/lambda but call it when applying the decorator.